# Range Slider width on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, mozilla

i'm building a custom video player and i'm using a input type range for the volume control, the thing is that i cant make the width lower then 300 pixels on firefox, any suggestions?

[image]

markups:

```
<div id="controls">
   <div id="progressBar"><span id="progress"></span></div>
       <button onclick="togglePlayPause()" id="playpause" title="play"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-play"></i></button>
        <div id="volume-controls">
           <button id="mute" onclick="toggleMute()"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-volume-up"></i></button>
           <input id="volume" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" type="range" onchange="setVolume()" />  
        </div>       
   </div>                         
</div>
```

my css:

```
input[type="range"] {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   border: 1px solid white;
   margin-top: 8px;
   width: 100px;
}
```

Works properly on chrome

Comment: Please provide your code, and let us know what you tried.

Comment: Code added, the width: 100px is working properly on google chrome

Comment: its working fine in firefox

Comment: I think its because <input /> is an inline element that you are unable to change its width ?